# second drop down in cascading drop down list not loading(ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, drop

please can anyone help me resolve this, i get no errors but the second drop down does not load and it seems the data is not binding?

**THE JQUERY**

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var items = "<option value= '0'>Select</option>";
        $('#CitiesId').html(items);
    });

    $('#ProvinceId').change(function () {
               
        $.getJSON("Vendors / GetCityList", { ProvinceId: $("#ProvinceId").val() }, function (data) {
            var items = '';
            $("#CitiesId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, Cities) {
                items += "<option value='" + Cities.value + "'>" + Cities.text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#CitiesId').html(items);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**THE CONTROLLER**

```
public JsonResult GetCity(int ProvinceId)
        {
            List<Cities> CitiesList = new List<Cities>();
            CitiesList = (from Cities in _context.Cities where Cities.ProvinceId == ProvinceId select   Cities).ToList();
            CitiesList.Insert(0, new Cities { CitiesID = 0, CitiesName = "Select" });
            return Json(new SelectList(CitiesList, "CitiesId", "CitiesName"));

        }
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
           
           
            List<Province> ProvinceList = new List<Province>();
            ProvinceList = (from Province in _context.Provinces select Province).ToList();

            ProvinceList.Insert(0, new Province { ProvinceId = 0, ProvinceName = "Select" });
            ViewBag.ListofProvince = ProvinceList;
            return View();

        }
```

**THE VIEW**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for=" Province" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="ProvinceId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofProvince, "ProvinceId", "ProvinceName"))"></</select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">City</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="CitiesId" name="CitiesId" asp-for="CitiesId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty,"CitiesId", "CitiesName"))"></select>

                    </div>
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo:

Cities:

```
 public class Cities
    {
        public int CitiesId { get; set; }
        public string CitiesName { get; set; }
    }
```

Province:

```
public class Province {
        public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
        public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
    }
```

DefaultController(I use fake data to test):

```
public JsonResult GetCity(int ProvinceId)
    {
        List<Cities> CitiesList = new List<Cities>();
        CitiesList.Insert(0, new Cities { CitiesId = 0, CitiesName = "Select" });
        CitiesList.Insert(1, new Cities { CitiesId = 1, CitiesName = "Select1" });
        CitiesList.Insert(2, new Cities { CitiesId = 2, CitiesName = "Select2" });

        return Json(new SelectList(CitiesList, "CitiesId", "CitiesName"));

    }
    public IActionResult Create()
    {


        List<Province> ProvinceList = new List<Province>();
        ProvinceList.Insert(0, new Province { ProvinceId = 0, ProvinceName = "Select" });
        ProvinceList.Insert(1, new Province { ProvinceId = 1, ProvinceName = "Select1" });
        ProvinceList.Insert(2, new Province { ProvinceId = 2, ProvinceName = "Select2" });
        ViewBag.ListofProvince = ProvinceList;
        return View();

    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="Province" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="ProvinceId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListofProvince, "ProvinceId", "ProvinceName"))"></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">City</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="CitiesId" name="CitiesId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty,"CitiesId", "CitiesName"))"></select>

</div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var items = "<option value= '0'>Select</option>";
            $('#CitiesId').html(items);
        });

        $('#ProvinceId').change(function () {
            //I use DefaultController,so I change the Url,If you use a controller named Vendors,you can use url like `/Vendors/GetCity`
            $.getJSON("/Default/GetCity", { ProvinceId: $("#ProvinceId").val() }, function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#CitiesId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, Cities) {
                    items += "<option value='" + Cities.value + "'>" + Cities.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#CitiesId').html(items);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: this is similar to what i did, I am just wondering why it doesn't load on my end.i suspected the jquery script but it works for you.if you seed the data to the DB context,would it be any different?

Comment: I tested with dbcontext,it's ok.Do you have data in dbcontext?And in your console,can you see any error.

Comment: I have figured out my error, "CitiesID" vs "CitiesId"

Comment: You mean `CitiesList.Insert(0, new Cities { CitiesID = 0, CitiesName = "Select" });`?

Comment: Yes,I should have written 'CitiesId' but had 'CitiesID'. It was a typo error,the code works well.